# django formwizard django-paypal

Tags: django, django-paypal

I'm struggling with getting the PayPalPaymentsForm to render in the FormWizard.

[ django 1.3, dcramer's django-paypal ]

The first 2 forms render and validate fine but I don't have the skills to pass the initial data to the form and to render the form with form.sandbox()

```
# urls.py
...
(r'^signup/$', SignUpWizard([SignUpForm1, SignUpForm2, SignUpForm3])),
...


# forms.py
...
class SignUpForm3(PayPalPaymentsForm):
    pass

class SignUpWizard(FormWizard):

def done(self, request, form_list):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/signup/success/')
```

I've had a look at the render_template() FormWizard method but none of my effots worked.

So, i'm going round in circles with no success. Any pointers most appreciated.

Comment: what looks like SignUpForm1 and SignUpForm2 ?